# remove the underline from the href link

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to remove the underline from a href link in ionic item:

```
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item  href="#/missionDetail/{{item.id}}" ng-class="{'star':item.star}" class="select item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in payloadFicheStatut | filter:query">
    <h2>{{item.codeDeFicheDeMission}}</h2>
    <button class="button button-clear icon ion-star button-assertive"
            ng-click="toggleStar(item)" ng-show="item.star">
    </button>
    <ion-option-button class="button-dark"
                       ng-click="toggleStar(item)">
      <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
    </ion-option-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use css.  `ion-item { text-decoration: none }`

Comment: a is an element and not an attribute

Comment: Sorry.  I mistyped.  I edited my answer to accurately depict what you're asking.

Comment: What element gets the underline?

Comment: ion-item because of the href

Comment: ion-item injects anchor tag as inner html if href/nghref/sref is present else adds div element...have you addded your css files after ionic css file? If that is the case try to add !important for .item-content...item-content class is added by ionic framework for div or anchor element inside ion-item...https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/1.x/js/angular/directive/item.js#L1  check this document to understand more about ion-item

Comment: thank you Anirudh for the answer...it works..please marke your comment as answer to be able to check it as correct answer

Comment: Thank you!  That helps a lot.  :)

Answer (score 1):

style.css

```
.underline {
  border-width: 0px;}
```

html

```
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item underline">
                <span class="input-label"><strong>ID</strong></span>
                <input type="text" placeholder=""/>
            </label>
            <label class="item underline">
                <span class="input-label"><strong>Password</strong></span>
                <input type="password" placeholder=""/>
            </label>
        </div>
```

want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

ion-item injects anchor tag as inner html if `href/nghref/sref` is present else adds `div` element...have you addded your css files after ionic css file? If that is the case try to add `!important` for `.item-content`...item-content class is added by ionic framework for div or anchor element inside ion-item...
[ionic documentation](http://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/1.x/js/angular/dir%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bective/)
check ionic document to understand more about ion-item

```
    .item-content {
         text-decoration: none !important;
     }
```